# Google Custom Search API showing old results

Tags: google-api, google-search, google-custom-search, google-search-api

I am trying to use the Google Custom Search API to show my ranking results on a regular basis. The only problem is that the displayed results seem to be fairly inaccurate, almost as if they are results from a month ago. The reason I know this, is that I searched for a famous person and it ranked a month old article. Is this normal for a Google search API? Is there a way I can get updated results?

I've checked the Google documentation but couldn't find anything.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Custom search API should be fairly accurate, alot of people use it (including myself) to check their SERP on a regular basis. Things like Famous people aren't going to change that much.. In order to compare results from custom search api to an actual search you could run some additional code inline, which does the search by making a curl request to your local google search engine and compare the results to the results of the search API.

Comment: "Things like famous people aren't going to change that much" - I really disagree with this. The search results of any famous person will constantly be changing because of all the news articles written about them. Search a celebrity you know had some big news about them in the last month. In google search (not news) it will show a page about this on the first page of results. However, the API will show pages way older than the ones found.

I've tried my own web pages which have recently started ranking in google. They appear on google search but are no where to be seen when using the API...

Comment: Fair enough.. but still - it works for everyone else. I've suggested a way to actually test it... Post your results :)